Синонимизировать [tuple] и [кортежи]
Существуют две идентичные по смыслу метки:

кортежи — 36 вопросов, есть описание.
tuple — 95 вопросов, нет описания.

Надо бы их синонимизировать. Главная, вероятно, кортежи, потому что она на русском и у неё есть описание.

Tuple - это класс в c#

@Grundy, [tuple] [c#] — 5 вопросов, [tuple][python] — 90. Проще создать отдельную метку [tag:c#-tuple].

это было к тому, что вопросы бывают по конкретным классам Tuple, а не по кортежам в общем

@Grundy как выше предложено, для этого можно создать метку с префиксом языка. Это не кажется мне проблемой.

@aepot [meta-tag:модераторский-произвол]

@Grundy твоя любимая, знаю.

@aepot имхо, отдельная метка [c#-tuple] не нужна, так как можно покрыть парой [c#] + [tuple]. Вряд ли мы ожидаем одновременного использования чего-то типа [rust] + [c#-tuple] без [c#]

updating post history, 113 rows affected (pipe delimited)
updating posts, 95 rows affected  (pipe delimited)
updating PostTags associations, 91 rows affected
updating ForYou nudges, 0 rows affected
destroying 'tuple': [tuple] removed from (0 post, 0 history, 1 tag)
total: 1 tags deleted, 0 posts modified, 0 post histories modified
0 history records for type Question had empty tags; retagged to [untagged]
0 post records of type Question had empty tags; retagged to [untagged]
updating count for target tag, new count: 127
tag remapping of [кортежи] and [tuple] complete!
remapping 0 synonyms
0 favorite and ignored tags remapped!
0 tracked tag badges were remapped!


Ничего себе, как быстро! Получаса не прошло.

поторопился ...

@Grundy опять этот модератор меня минусует. :(

@aepot Добро пожаловать.
